# Possible ways to access template input variable (*ngFor variable) outside the loop?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is there any way to access ***ngFor** variable **item** outside the current div. in my case the **booking(item)** method not able to access **item** variable. *any possible way?*

```
<div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <small>
        <img [src]="item.imagePath" alt="{{item.name}}"
            class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 100px" width="120px">
        <p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>
        <p>Price: {{item.price}}</p>

      <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteItem(item)">X</button>
      <hr/>         
    </small>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="booking(item)" 
        style="margin-right: 30px;">Book Now</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to put it inside the div. If you want to preserve your structure, then you should wrap your code in another div and have that use the ngFor directive instead.

The way ngFor works, is it will create an element (in your case, the `<div class="cart-item">` multiple times, once for each item in the loop. The button will be placed after all the cart item elements, so how could it know which item it should refer to?

I think what you're trying to do is to put one button for each of your cart items. in this case, you would modify your code as following:

```
<div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of items"> 
  <small> 
    <img [src]="item.imagePath" alt="{{item.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 100px" width="120px"/> 
    <p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>       
    <p>Price: {{item.price}}</p> 
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteItem(item)">X</button> 
    <hr/> 
  </small> 

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="booking(item)" style="margin-right: 30px;">Book Now</button>
</div>
```

or, if you'd like to preserve your structure:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="cart-item"> 
    <small> 
      <img [src]="item.imagePath" alt="{{item.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 100px" width="120px"/> 
      <p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>       
      <p>Price: {{item.price}}</p> 
      <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteItem(item)">X</button> 
      <hr/> 
    </small> 
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="booking(item)" style="margin-right: 30px;">Book Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: think of it like a for loop in javascript. the opening and closing tags (`<div>` and `</div>` are like opening and closing brackets (`{` and `}`). your `item` variable lives only inside of the scope of the for loop and won't be accessible from the code placed after the loop.

Comment: if i will do like you did above i will get Book Now button of each item in my cart. that's i don't want. there will be only one Book Now button.

Comment: then you need some way to determine which item should be called in the booking method. consider using a form where you can add a checkbox for each item, or something similar.

Comment: if i will pass items(not item) then it will pass all item available in cart to booking method?

Comment: you could add a click event to the div which will select the clicked item for booking. add a field `selectedItem` to your component and set it when the user clicks on it like so: `(click)="select(item)"`. you'll need to implement the select() method in your component. then your button can just invoke `booking()`, inside of which you access `this->selectedItem`.

Comment: but this will help me to book a single item.my aim is to store n number of items in cart and there will be a single Book Now button when i click on it, it will book all items of my cart.

Comment: when i am doing this booking(items) there is 2 items in my cart. it getting booked what i am get in console is `[Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: {id: 5, name: "Eternis", …}
1: {id: 4, name: "Sprenza", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`. problem is i am not able to access this data.

Comment: Should i access this array like this `*ngFor="let item of bookedItems[0]" `